# Organization members not allowed to access private pages of the organization site

Tags: liferay-6

With Liferay 6.1 CE, when an organization member attempt to access a private page of the organization site, he obtains the following error :

> You do not have permission to view this page.

In the log file liferay.2012-06-06.log, we can read the following message :

> 13:54:42,149 INFO [PortalImpl:4890] User 524603 is not allowed to
>   access the private pages of group 503050

For information, the *Membership* type of the organization is *private*.
If we add the *Site administrator* role to the member, then the access is allowed to the private pages of the organization site.

It seems that the error appears for public pages of an organization site too.

> 14:11:46,782 INFO [PortalImpl:4890] User 524603 is not allowed to
>   access the public pages of group 503050

Both errors appear even after deletion of the organization site and new creation of it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the user to the Site as Site Member, and add the user to Organization as.